# Compilation errors with clang when using a custom trait and a c++11 enum of type bool

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, clang

The following code compiles fine with g++ and fails with clang (all versions I've tested):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace has_insertion_operator_impl
{
    typedef char no;
    typedef char yes[2];

    struct any_t
    {
        template <typename T>
        any_t(const T&);
    };

    yes& testStreamable(std::ostream&);
    no   testStreamable(no);

    no operator<<(const std::ostream&, const any_t&);

    template <typename T>
    struct has_insertion_operator
    {
        static std::ostream& s;
        static const T& t;
        static const bool value = sizeof(testStreamable(s << t)) == sizeof(yes);
    };
} // namespace has_insertion_operator_impl

template <typename T>
struct has_insertion_operator : has_insertion_operator_impl::has_insertion_operator<T>
{};

enum A : bool {
    Yup = true,
    Nop = false,
};

template <typename T>
bool getTraitVal(const T&) { return has_insertion_operator<T>::value; }

int main() { std::cout << getTraitVal(A::Yup) << std::endl; }
```

The error (with clang only!) is this:

```
prog.cc:24:59: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const A')
        static const bool value = sizeof(testStreamable(s << t)) == sizeof(yes);
```

I believe this is a small enough example. Here are links to online compilers for it:

- [clang 3.8](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ywLCIsZPaaF0btxc)
- [g++ 6.1](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KJ1K8Sp8MeIl1T2Y)

When I change the enum type from bool to int - the error disappears.

So why is this happening? This was originally discovered when using the [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) and [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) testing frameworks - here is the [bug report](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/issues/742) for Catch. Could it be a clang bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it doesn't answer your question, but it seems clang has a problem with enums of underlying type 'bool'.

I further reduced your example to:

```
#include <iostream>

enum A : bool {
    Yup = true,
    Nop = false,
};

int main() { 
    A t = Yup;
    std::cout << t;
}
```

And here you can already have a feeling for what's happening:

```
prog.cc:10:15: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'A')
    std::cout << t;
    ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
/usr/local/libcxx-3.8/include/c++/v1/ostream:195:20: note: candidate function
    basic_ostream& operator<<(bool __n);
                   ^
/usr/local/libcxx-3.8/include/c++/v1/ostream:198:20: note: candidate function
    basic_ostream& operator<<(int __n);
                   ^
...
```

Comment: maybe we should try to submit a bug to clang - anyone got an account?

Comment: Filed the bug - see [here](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=31229)